# How to perform "Lookup" operation on Spark dataframes given multiple conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, lookup

I'm a newbie on Spark (My version is 1.6.0) and now I'm trying to solve the problem given below:

Suppose there are two source files:

- The first one (A for short) is a big one which contains columns named A1, B1, C1 and other 80 columns. There are 230K records inside.
- The second one (B for short) is a small lookup table which contains columns named A2, B2, C2 and D2. There are 250 records inside.

Now we need to insert a new column into A, given the logic below:

- First lookup A1, B1 and C1 in B (corresponding columns are A2, B2 and C2), if succeeds, return D2 as the value of the new added column. If nothing found...
- Then lookup A1, B1 in B. If successful, return D2. If nothing found...
- Set the default value "NA"

I have already read in the files and converted them into data frames. For the first situation, I got the result by left outer joining them together. But I cannot find good way in the next step.

My current trying is to build a new data frame by joining A and B using a less strict condition. However I've no clue how to update the current data frame from the other one. Or is there any other more intuitive and efficient way to tackle the whole problem?

Thanks for all the answers.

-----------------------------Update on 20160309--------------------------------

Finally accepted @mlk 's answer. Still great thanks to @zero323 for his/her great comments on UDF versus join, the Tungsten code generation is really another problem we are facing now. But since we need to do scores of lookup and average 4 conditions for every lookup, the former solution is more suitable...

The final solution is somehow looks like below snippet:

````
```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import com.github.marklister.collections.io._

case class TableType(A: String, B: String, C: String, D: String)
val tableBroadcast = sparkContext.broadcast(CsvParser(TableType).parseFile("..."))
val lkupD = udf {
  (aStr: String, bStr: String, cStr: String) =>
    tableBroadcast.value.find {
      case TableType(a, b, c, _) =>
        (a == aStr && b == bStr && c == cStr) ||
        (a == aStr && b == bStr)
    }.getOrElse(TableType("", "", "", "NA")).D
}
df = df.withColumn("NEW_COL", lkupD($"A", $"B", $"C"))
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As B is small I think the best way to do this would be a broadcast variable and user defined function.

```
// However you get the data...
case class BType( A2: Int, B2: Int, C2 : Int, D2 : String)
val B = Seq(BType(1,1,1,"B111"), BType(1,1,2, "B112"), BType(2,0,0, "B200"))

val A = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,1,1, "DATA"), (1,1,2, "DATA"), (2, 0, 0, "DATA"), (2, 0, 1, "NONE"), (3, 0, 0, "NONE"))).toDF("A1", "B1", "C1", "OTHER")


// Broadcast B so all nodes have a copy of it.
val Bbradcast = sc.broadcast(B)

// A user defined function to find the value for D2. This I'm sure could be improved by whacking it into maps. But this is a small example. 
val findD = udf {( a: Int, b : Int, c: Int) => Bbradcast.value.find(x => x.A2 == a && x.B2 == b && x.C2 == c).getOrElse(Bbradcast.value.find(x => x.A2 == a && x.B2 == b).getOrElse(BType(0,0,0,"NA"))).D2 }

// Use the UDF in a select
A.select($"A1", $"B1", $"C1", $"OTHER", findD($"A1", $"B1", $"C1").as("D")).show
```

Comment: This probably the way to go. I provided an alternative solution with `joins` as well.

Comment: Thanks mlk. If the lookup table is big (500K * 50), is it still good to broadcast it?

Comment: And my another question is, suppose I need to do 30 lookups on different columns, and write 50 UDFs, would the performance be affected?

Comment: Would the performance be affected vs what? Against joins? Would you need "50" joins to do the same thing? I don't know and would suggest you write some tests. My gut says the UDFs would be faster, but my gut also thought eating pizzas several times a weeks was a good idea.

Comment: As to size, does it (or the subset you need) fit in memory on each of your worker nodes? Yes - I'd likely broadcast it.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference a solution without UDFs:

```
val b1 = broadcast(b.toDF("A2_1", "B2_1", "C2_1", "D_1"))
val b2 = broadcast(b.toDF("A2_2", "B2_2", "C2_2", "D_2"))

// Match A, B and C
val expr1 = ($"A1" === $"A2_1") && ($"B1" === $"B2_1") && ($"C1" === $"C2_1")
// Match A and B mismatch C
val expr2 = ($"A1" === $"A2_2") && ($"B1" === $"B2_2") && ($"C1" !== $"C2_2")

val toDrop = b1.columns ++ b2.columns

toDrop.foldLeft(a
  .join(b1, expr1, "leftouter")
  .join(b2, expr2, "leftouter")
  // If there is match on A, B, C then D_1 should be not NULL
  // otherwise we fall-back to D_2 
  .withColumn("D", coalesce($"D_1", $"D_2")) 
)((df, c) => df.drop(c))
```

This assumes there is at most one match in each category (all three columns, or the first two) or duplicate rows in the output are desired.

*UDF vs JOIN*:

There are multiple factors to consider and there is no simple answer here:

*Cons*:

- broadcast `joins` require passing data twice to the worker nodes. As for now `broadcasted` tables are not cached ([SPARK-3863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3863)) and it is unlikely to change in the nearest future (Resolution: Later).
- `join` operation is applied twice even if there is a full match.

*Pros*:

- `join` and `coalesce` are transparent to the optimizer while UDFs are not.
- operating directly with SQL expressions can benefit from all the Tungsten optimizations including code generation while UDF cannot.